# SQL Update Statement - update row based on non unique record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in Oracle db with 3 columns as follows

```
DealID  ---TradeID  -----LinkedID

10000 -------1   ------------Null

10000 -------2   ------------Null

10001 -------3   ------------Null

10001 -------4   ------------Null
```

I would like to write an SQL statement to update the linked id column to return the following updated table

```
DealID  ---TradeID  -----LinkedID

10000 -------1   -----------2

10000 -------2   -----------1

10001 -------3   -----------4

10001 -------4   -----------3
```

For each deal id and trade id combination, find the other trade id also linked to that deal id and update the record with this value as the linked id.
Each deal id has 2 different trade ids. (trade ids are unique)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated update:

```
update
    table
set
    LinkedID = (
        select 
            TradeID 
        from 
            table t 
        where 
            table.DealID = t.DealID and 
            table.TradeID != t.TradeID
    )
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4ba6e/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table_name dest
   SET linkedID = (SELECT src.tradeID
                     FROM table_name src
                    WHERE src.dealID = dest.dealID
                      AND src.rowid != dest.rowid )
```

will update every row in the table.  This assumes that every `dealID` has exactly two `tradeID` rows in the table.

From a data model standpoint, this sort of cross-linkage would seem to be rather problematic.  I'd strongly suggest normalizing the data.  It sounds like trades are associated with deals so there probably ought to be a `deal` table, a `trades` table, and a 1:n table to link trades with deals.